# is this code right? (PHP POST method using catpcha)

Tags: php, captcha

I am a very rookie php developer; and i decided create a user Login system. 
For the system, i want use captcha system. My problem is that when i click the button "Send" i can't send the data of the form (two textbox: username and mail address).
For make it work; i created a method that recive the data of the form, this data is send like: method_name($POST["username"],$POST["mail"]);
i want to know if this is correct or it will have some security problem or maybe something else.

thanks.

pd: sorry for my english...is not good. 
**this is the index page**

```
    <?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
require_once('home.php');

$publickey = "foo";
$privatekey = "bar";

$error = null;

if ($_POST['action'] == "register") {
    $re_ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $re_challenge = $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"];
    $re_response = $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"];

    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer($privatekey, $re_ip, $re_challenge, $re_response);

    if ($resp->is_valid) {
        // procesar registro
            hello($_POST["username"],$_POST["usermail"]);
        exit;
    } else {
        $error = $resp->error;
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>reCAPTCHA Demo</title>
<style type="text/css">

body {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #333;
    line-height: 18px;
}
.casilla {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #333;
    padding: 2px 4px;
    width: 298px;
    margin-left: 3px;
}
h3 {
    color: #03C;
    font-size: 16px;
}

</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/css3buttons.css" media="screen"/>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Registro</h3>
<form method="post">
    <label for="username">Usuario</label><br />
    <input name="username" type="text" class="casilla" id="username" /><br />
    <label for="usermail">Email</label><br />
    <input name="usermail" type="text" class="casilla" id="usermail" /><br />
    <label for="usercheck">Verificaci&oacute;n</label><br />
    <?php echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey, $error); ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="register" />
    <button type="submit" name="btsend" value="Enviar">Iniciar Sesión</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
**and this is other page**

    <!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        function hello($var1,$var2)
        {
            $mailFilter = "^(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+([;.](([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+)*$";
            echo"HELLO WORLD\n".$var1."---".$var2;
            if (preg_match($mailFilter, $var2)) {
            echo "A match was found.";
            } else {
                echo "correo valido.";
            }
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: **PLEASE**, don't post your private keys. It's *not* a good idea.

Comment: yes you're right. i wont do this again.

Comment: Email team@stackoverflow.com if you need to get the edit history reversed, but since your private keys have already been compromised, your best bet may be to get new ones.

Answer (score 1):

If the form cannot be sent, then I would assume because the form declaration lacks the `action=` URL. Normally you would write:

```
 <form method="POST" action="index.php">
```

The second thing is the email regex. It misses the typical valid characters, but also doesn't use correct PCRE delimiters. Rather use this instead of a manual `preg_match $mailFilter`:

```
 if (filter_var($var2, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
```

Comment: I had already tried as you mentioned, but I think the error is here:
 if ($resp->is_valid) {
        // when i click in send button, the code enter here.
        // if i dont call my function hello(...) the code dont do anything
            hello($_POST["username"],$_POST["usermail"]);
        exit;
    } else {
        $error = $resp->error;
    }

Comment: Well, do you get any error message? Else try `if ($resp && $resp->is_valid) {` instead.

Comment: any error message is show it. i tried 
if ($resp && $resp->is_valid) {...
and i see that the url change to localhost/home.php. so the code if it comes to the other file: home.php
but does nothing.

Comment: is very disappointing to see that the error was very clear.
when i tried to do as you had mentioned, I put:
print $ POST ["ID"], when it should be: print $ _POST ["ID"];
now all is fine.
I will have more care with the syntax of my code, I made you lose time, I'm sorry. And thank you very much for everything!

Comment: How did the URL change? I'm confused with your example. Maybe you should explain the file parts. Or are these actually two files? Then the `if($_POST...` check blongs in the receiving script.

Comment: No worries. It's interesting nevertheless.